# How to append string in paragraph left &right side in the same line

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using the below code with this code I am getting Fdesc and the amount left side. I want to show the description right side and the amount on the left side.

```
DataTable billingDt = estimate.Tables[1];
// first check for {BillingT&M}
var docBillingTMTag = document.FindUniqueByPattern(@"{BillingT&M[ ]*:[ ]*[0-9]*,[ a-zA-Z]*,[ a-zA-Z]*}", RegexOptions.Singleline);
docBillingTMTag.AddRange(document.FindUniqueByPattern(@"{BillingT&M}", RegexOptions.Singleline));
if (docBillingTMTag.Count > 0)
{
    Novacode.Paragraph docParaBillingTM = document.Paragraphs.Where(x => x.Text.Contains(docBillingTMTag.FirstOrDefault())).FirstOrDefault();
    docParaBillingTM.Alignment = Alignment.left;
   
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in billingDt.Rows)
    {
        docParaBillingTM.AppendLine(dataRow["fDesc"].ToString() + ": " + Convert.ToDecimal(dataRow["Amount"] == DBNull.Value ? "0.00" : dataRow["Amount"]).ToString("C"));
    }
```